# Program flow of displaying output in reverse

Tags: c, string, loops

1.I have this sample program in C that accepts positive inputs from users and stops when the user inputs negative numbers. It accepts a maximum of ten inputs. It then displays the result in reverse order. I'm wondering how does that happen because when I try to map it the value of c is negative, the second loop will only work if the condition (c>=0) is satisfied.
Example if I input only one positive number and I will  input a negative number next.

```
input[0]=2     
i=0+1    
c=1-2

input[1]=-4
i=1+1    
c=2-2       

num=2*input[-1]?
```

---

```
    #include<stdio.h>

int main()  
{    
        float in;    

    float input[10];
    int i=0;
    int c;

    printf("Please input a number:");
    do{ scanf("%f", &in);
            input[i] = in;

            i=i+1;

            if(i>10)
                break;

            c=i-1;      
    }while(in>=0);

    do{     float num;
            num= 2*input[c];
            printf("Input = %.2f.  Num= %.2f.\n", input[c], num);

            c=c-1;
    }while(c>=0);

    return 0;
}
```

The input using the do-while code:
   2
   3
   -4
 The output:
  Input:3.00      Output:6.00
  Input:2.00     Output: 4.00

1. And When I try to implement it using for loop, it compiled in gcc but when I try to execute it displays `segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

   ```
   #include<stdio.h>
   ```

   int main()
   {   float in;
       float input[10];
       int i,c;

   ```
   printf("Please input a number:");

   for(i=0; in>=0; ){
       scanf("%f", &in);       
       input[i] = in;
       i=i+1;      
       if(i==10)
           break;      
       c=i-2;
   }

   for(; c>=0;){
       float num;
       num= 2*input[c];
       printf("Input = %.2f.  Num= %.2f.\n", input[c], num);
       c=c-1;
   }

   return 0;
   ```

   }

Comment: For starters, your first `for-loop` is invoking **undefined behavior**. You evaluate `in` with your conditional expression without ever assigning or initializing its value prior to the first iteration. And I've no idea why you're doing this: `c=i-2;`. And... you never check the return result of `scanf()` so there is no assuredness it actually *worked*.

Comment: replacing'in>=0' with 'input[i]', it accepts 1 input only regardless of sign.In the above code that uses do-while c=i-2 is used to reverse the output, but I have no idea how that worked because when I try to map it out c is negative. The code that uses do-while already worked.

Comment: That isn't any better. `input[]` is also uninitialized. Frankly I'm still lost what this is trying to do. Is this supposed to take a list of floats from the user, and upon reaching 10 entries or a negative input number, print numbers successfully input in reverse order? If so, you're making this much harder than you need to.([See it live](http://ideone.com/QS30K7)). If not, it needs more explanation (at least for me).

Comment: I edited the post.The code that uses for-loop is supposed to display the same output as the first code that uses do-while. It stops when input is negative and it reaches 10 inputs.

Comment: your for loop version runs for me on windows. but still has the problem your do while version has.

Comment: `if(i>10)` ---> `if(i>=10)`

Answer (score 0):

`I'm wondering how does that happen because when I try to map it the value of c is negative`

I don't think c does go negitive, when i try to map it with `2` & `-4` as inputs i get..

When you enter `2`;
it makes `input[i] = 2` (`i` is equal to 0) then after that `i` is incremented to 1.
and then it makes `c = i - 1` or `c = 1 - 1` or `c = 0`.
doesn't quit because `in >= 0` (2).
When you enter `-4`;
i makes `input[i] = -4` (`i` is equal to 1, c is equal to 0) then after i is incremented to 2
and then it makes `c = i - 1` or `c = 2 - 1` or `c = 1`.
this time quits because `in < 0` & not  `in >= 0`.

```
do{ scanf("%f", &in);
        input[i] = in;

        i=i+1;

        if(i>10)
            break;

        c=i-1;      
} while (in >=0)
```